# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException in Android

Tags: android, authentication, jakarta-mail

I receive the below error message in my LogCat when trying to send an email from my Gmail account using JavaMail API.

```
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443): javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443):    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443):    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443):    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443):    at com.srindroid.sendemail.MainActivity$RetrievedFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:88)
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443):    at com.srindroid.sendemail.MainActivity$RetrievedFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-09 11:04:14.385: W/System.err(18443):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**Source Code**

```
package com.srindroid.sendemail;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Session session = null;
    ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
    Context context = null;
    EditText rec, subject, message;
    String strRec, strSubject, strMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;

        Button submit = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnSendEmail);
        rec = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.txtToEmail);
        subject = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.txtSubject);
        message = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.txtMessage);

        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        strRec = rec.getText().toString();
        strSubject = subject.getText().toString();
        strMessage = subject.getText().toString();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                return new PasswordAuthentication("indianclassics27@gmail.com",**<MyPassword>**);               
            }
        });

        pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Send Email", "Sending Email...");
        RetrievedFeedTask task = new RetrievedFeedTask();
        task.execute();

    }

    class RetrievedFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try{

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("indianclassics27@gmail.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(strRec));
                message.setSubject(strSubject);
                message.setContent(strMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

                Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                transport.connect();
                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());


            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pdialog.dismiss();
            rec.setText("");
            subject.setText("");
            message.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Could you please help me in understanding on what creates this AuthenticationFailedException? Please note that when I use the same credentials in www.gmail.com, I'm able to successfully login into my email account.

Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 9):

First, fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Turn on [Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to see if the protocol trace gives any more clues about what's wrong.

You may need to [enable access for less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

Comment: I'm not sure at what point this fixed it because I was still getting an error caused by something else, but it did work. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for such great answer . third one help for me .. i am not able to send message because Less Secure App turn Off .

Answer (score 8):

go to your mail and then click on my account and then select Sign-in & security option

and then on bottom show Allow less secure apps: OFF is off so ON this option and now you can send background mail.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Final Solution**
After losing many days I found this solution. you should enable Two-Factor Authentication in your Gmail account and then create App Password by fellow these steps:

1. Go to your Google Account.
2. Select Security.
3. Under "Signing in to Google," select App Passwords. You may need to sign in. If you don’t have this option, it might be because:

- 2-Step Verification is not set up for your account.
- 2-Step Verification is only set up for security keys.
- Your account is through work, school, or other organizations.
- You turned on Advanced Protection.

4. At the bottom, choose Select app and choose the app you using and then Select the device and choose the device you’re using and then Generate.
5. Follow the instructions to enter the App Password. The App Password is the 16-character code in the yellow bar on your device.
6. Tap Done.

after that copy the generated password and paste it into your JavaMail password section.

Good luck.