# error: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email without user interaction and i am taking reference from [This site](http://www.edumobile.org/android/send-email-on-button-click-without-email-chooser/)
But i am getting the following exception

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

i have tried many solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825425/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-in-android),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544173/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-on-sending-email-through-java-mail-liba) and many other but nothing happened 
below is my activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button addImage =  findViewById(R.id.button);
        addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new SendMail().execute("");
            }
        });
    }
    private class SendMail extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Sending mail", true, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            Mail m = new Mail("saifali.webappmate@gmail", "**********");

            String[] toArr = {"shashwat.webappmate@gmail", "saifali.webappmate@gmail"};
            m.setTo(toArr);
            m.setFrom("saifali.webappmate@gmail.com");
            m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device.");
            m.setBody("Email body.");

            try {
                if(m.send()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

If anybody has any better solution please suggest me.
Thanks.

Comment: First don't use Pokemon exception handling, secondly can you pass the log?

Comment: The link you started from is out of date.  See the [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android) page.  See also the [Gmail instructions in the JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail).  If it still doesn't work, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).